# Calling user follow/follower list in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Hi Djangonauts,
                  I am trying to get the user follows list(example like Instagram 'A' follows 'B') in the templates. I have tried almost everything I am not able to call it in the templates. What am I doing wrong

**My models** (It's a monkey patch to the Django User model)

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #other profile fields


class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='supporter')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='leader')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


User.add_to_class(
    'following',
    models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', 
        through=Contact, 
        related_name='followers', 
        symmetrical=False))
```

**My views** (not sure if this is correct)

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['follows'] = Contact.objects.filter(
        user_from__isnull=False,
        user_from__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    context['followers'] = Contact.objects.filter(
        user_to__isnull=False,
        user_to__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return context
```

**My Templates**

```
{{user}} follows {{user.supporter.count}} members #This works shows the correct number
        {% for contact in Contact.objects.all %}
            {{contact.user_to.username}} # I am not able to get this part to work
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit that isn't working is the loop, because `Contact` is not defined in the template. But I don't understand why you think you need to access it. You should be looping through the many-to-many field on the user:

```
{% for follow in user.following.all %} 
    {{ follow.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I don't even need the context in the views.py

Comment: No I don't think so.

Comment: I am sorry there is a small correction in your answer
 its {{ follow.username }}